# Flurl/HttpClient messes up memory on simultaneous requests using IoC

Tags: c#, httpclient, flurl

We are using Flurl to upload many files at once in our Web API app (.net 6). Usually, from 20 to 30 simultaneous uploads are executed.

I am trying to manage Flurl instances explicitly and use IoC. The code below works fine for a small number of parallel uploads, but if simultaneous request counts reach around 30, the CPU and Memory consumption for our app go mad, the memory jumping from 1GB to a total of 5GB RAM, CPU usage goes from 20 to 100% and back and app hangs in that state!

If I use `new Url` and leave Flurl to manage instances, everything works fine. Any idea what may cause such behavior?

```
public class BuildFileServer : IBuildFileServer
{

    private readonly IFlurlClient _client;

    public BuildFileServer(IFlurlClient client)
    {
        _client = client;
    }

 public async Task<StoreFile> StoreAsync(FileInfo file)
    {
        var fileUploadResultDto = await
            _client.Request("upload")
                .WithHeader("accept", "application/json")
                .WithHeader("content-type", MimeMapping.MimeUtility.GetMimeMapping(fileName))
                .WithHeader("content-disposition", new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
                {
                    Name = "file",
                    FileName = fileName,
                    FileNameStar = fileName
                })
                .PostAsync(new FileContent(file.FullName))
                .ReceiveJson<FileUploadResultDto>();

        return ///....
    }
}

public static class FileServerDiRegistry
{
    public static void AddFileServer(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IFlurlClient>(serviceProvider =>
        {
            var client = new FlurlClient(new Url
            {
                Scheme = "http",
                Host = AppConstants.CfsHost,
                Port = AppConstants.CfsPort
            });



            client.Configure(settings =>
            {
                settings.OnErrorAsync = async (httpCall) =>
                {

                };

                settings.AfterCallAsync = async (httpCall) =>
                {

                };
            });

            return client;
        });
    }
}

    builder.Services.AddFileServer();
```

This is code that works stable.

```
public class BuildFileServer : IBuildFileServer
{
   public async Task<StoreFile> StoreAsync(FileInfo file)
    {

      var url = new Url
        {
            Scheme = ServerSchema,
            Host = ServerHost,
            Path = "upload",
            Port = ServerPort
        };


        var fileUploadResultDto = await
            url
                .WithHeader("accept", "application/json")
                .WithHeader("content-type", MimeMapping.MimeUtility.GetMimeMapping(fileName))
                .WithHeader("content-disposition", new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
                {
                    Name = "file",
                    FileName = fileName,
                    FileNameStar = fileName
                })
                .PostAsync(new FileContent(file.FullName))
                .ReceiveJson<FileUploadResultDto>();

        return ///....
    }
}
```

Comment: In the first sample you're setting up event handlers (OnErrorAsync  and AfterCallAsync) but not in the second. Are they truly empty or did you exclude the bodies for clarity? Other than that I honestly don't see anything here that would cause these to behave differently.

Comment: @ToddMenier They had a logging method, but I have removed them and tested again. No difference, the same problem. I will try to debug more. Todd, Do you have some recommendations on the best method to upload tens of files from one task simultaneous?